# Find offset and page number given paged virtual memory address

Tags: memory-management, memory-access, virtual-memory, c

I ran into this question in class:
Assume a machine that is 64-bit and has 8GB memory. They use a paged virtual memory where the page size is 4KB. You run the following program:

```
int main() {
   int *ptr = malloc(16);
   printf("%p\n", ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

and get output:
0x555555756260

We're to find the virtual page number of the address and the offset.

What I'm thinking is that I first convert that to binary, figure out how many bits and which bits represent the address/offset.

But I'm not sure how to figure out the latter. How can I determine which bits in the address correspond to which?

I'd really love some guidance

Comment: 4K is $2^{12}$. Each hex digit represents four binary ones.

Comment: @greybeard how do I find out which hex digits correspond with the page number and the offset? Like is the offset the last 24 bits or...?

Comment: This question most probably came up in some environment introducing into implementation of computers (using electronic circuitry for now). It would seem time to revisit whatever material there is on *paged memory*. While the offset is in the less significant part, even with *bit addressable memory* it would not take 24 bits to identify one cell in a `4KB` page.

Answer (score 0):

- *assume* address printed out to be a "byte address"
- *guess* whether the offset to find is *addressable unit in page* or *byte in page*

  - if *addressable unit in page*, figure out its size
    with nothing more than *64-bit* to go on a first **assumption** is 8 bytes
- guess the representation wanted for *virtual page number* & *offset*

(Base conversions in the process depend on practice with the representations involved. For a result in hex, too, some would prefer to just double (word offset) or halve ("byte page#") "in hex". A *coder* might have a program print both parts before even considering if coding the task was least effort.)

Comment: For a bonus of 4 rubber points: What has the amount of memory been specified for?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting to binary, it is more convenient to convert the page size to hexadecimal ($\text{0x10000}$). This hints you which are the significant hex-digits in the address.